# How to prove this proposition?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proposition:

Let $\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n=1}$, $\left \{ y_n \right \}_{n=1}$ be sequences of positive real numbers such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $y_n \rightarrow \infty $. Then,
$$\left ( 1+\frac{x_n}{y_n} \right )^{y_n} \rightarrow 1 .$$

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 6):

Using the identity $0\leq \log(1+t)\leq t$ for $t\geq 0$, we have
$$ 0\leq \log\Big[\Big(1+\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Big)^{y_n}\Big]=y_n\log\Big(1+\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Big)\leq y_n\cdot \frac{x_n}{y_n}=x_n $$

Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\Big[\Big(1+\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Big)^{y_n}\Big]=0$ by the squeeze theorem, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Big)^{y_n}=1$.